# Rails 4 asset_path returning different path in custom class than in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

When I run `<% asset_path "example.png" %>` it returns `/assets/example.png` as expected.
However, when I run `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('example.png')` from within a custom class or within the console, it returns `/example.png`.

Can anyone tell me why it works this way and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: For me it returns a path without `/assets/` if the file I am pointing at does not exist, so sprockets fails to precompile asset. Where is your `example.png` located and what is your environment?

Comment: This was exactly it. Could have sworn the manual browser tests using real images weren't working, but started using a existing image in the specs and started working as expected. Thanks so much!